# How to initialize objects, so that the Garbage Collector has to do less work

Tags: java, android, memory-management, garbage-collection

What is the difference between these two forms of code in android and java..

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    Student s = myMap.get(key);
    // do stuff
}
```

and:

```
Student s;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    s = myMap.get(key);
    // do stuff
}
```

The first one creates 10000 objects waiting the garbage collector to remove them from memory while in the second form of code only one object has been created. Am I right? Or I got it all wrong?

If this is true, is it better for memory then to use the second form?

Answer (score 7):

You're wrong and there's no reason why you should use the second form.

There is 0 objects created, the only difference is the scope of the variable. The objects have already been created, they're in the map. You're just assigning a reference to an existing object.

It's a good practice to declare variables in the smallest scope possible, so if you're not using `s` outside the loop (which wouldn't make sense, unless you wanted the last Student processed), it makes sense to declare it inside the loop.

Comment: To add to this, even if a new variable was created inside the loop it would be eligable for garbage collection as soon as the next cycle of the loop started. So the first example would still be better (although only marginally). In no case are 10000 waiting around for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign reference type object to variable you are not copying the object contents but instead just adding reference to it. Assignment does not create new objects. Function `myMap.get` does. In both cases there will be 10000 objects created and a single reference set. So, basically both code segments are roughly equally efficient, only first is better from best-practices perspective as it keeps the scope as small as possible in is more readable than the second one.